# counting in awk

Tags: awk

```
#!/bin/sh
find ${*-.} -type f -print | xargs file | 
awk '{
$1=NULL;
t[$0]++;
}
end {
for (i in t) printf("%d\t%s\n", t[i], i);
}' | sort -nr
```

The first "find" line works. But the awk part does not work. I expect the count of file types sorted in descending order.

Comment: I would suggest `find ${*-.} -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file |` in case there are filenames with spaces.

Comment: @Dennis, I agree, but that's GNU find and xargs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

awk is case sensitive - "end" should be "END"

Answer (score 2):

Use `END`, not `end`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a blank between the tick and the `{`:

```
awk ' {
```

Some versions of AWK need this.

Comment: I remember this from HP-UX from 1992.